# Objective-C Stop loading the view while in viewDidLoad from presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using the presentViewController method to present a subview as shown below.  However, I need to be able to stop the subview from loading if a valid license does not exist.  **I must do it from the subview.**

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"innerID-iOS-Resources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    if (bundle) {
        if (!self.cameraVC) {
            self.cameraVC = [[IDCameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IDCameraViewController" bundle:bundle];
        }
        [self.cameraVC willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:self.cameraVC];
        [self.view addSubview:self.cameraVC.view];
        [self.cameraVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

There is a callback method that calls the following closeCameraView method when done.  **I do not want to use another callback for when license does not exist.**

```
- (void)closeCameraView
{
    [self.cameraVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.cameraVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.cameraVC removeFromParentViewController];
    [self showControls];
}
```

The viewDidLoad is the first method that gets executed when the subview is presented.

**I want to check for a valid license and return to the calling view if one does not exist.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self isLicenseValid]) {
        self.cameraSettings = [IDCameraSettings cameraSettings];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"License Activation"
                                   message:@"A valid license must be activated for this product."
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        //Do not load view
    }
}
```

I've tried the following two approaches to no avail and am having difficulty finding similar questions/answers on the Internet.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Any ideas?  Please.

Thank you,
Lucy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the view is, as the method name suggests, already loaded. So you can't stop the view from loading at that point.

From the little bit of code you show, it looks like you could just call your `isLicenseValid` method on your view controller before you try to display it, since it's the act of trying to display it that will cause it to load its views.

Comment: The parent controller will belong to someone else's application.  I am exposing a xib file in a bundle from an SDK.  Is there no way to dismiss the view from its parent and make the parent the active view?

Comment: So... What you want to do is make it so that if someone else displays your view controller that it is immediately dismissed if this license isn't there? I think you just need to document how to properly use your view controller, meaning they need to explicitly check your `isLicenseValid` method before trying to display the view controller. As for if they go ahead and display it without doing this check first, your view controller should display an error dialog upon being displayed.

Comment: Thank you, Gavin, for your help.  I think we decided to add an NSNotification callback to inform them of invalid license and let their UI dismiss the subview.  Plus, that would allow our SDK users to put any notifications to their users in any language of their choice.

Comment: Also, we put the license check inside loadView, which stops the view from loading if the license does not exist.  YaY!!!